# Mockito verify calls in method called by constructor using InjectMocks

Tags: java, unit-testing, gwt, mockito

I am using InjectMocks with Mockito. Probably this is a stupid question but I wondered if there was a way to verify the behaviour of some of the mocks which get used during the constructor initialization. As I am using InjectMocks I don't explicitly create the object. For example

```
public class DatePanelTest {

   @Mock
   private DateBoxWithIcon dateBox;
   @Mock
   private FlexTable table;
   @Mock
   private TextBox textBox;

   @InjectMocks
   private DatePanel panel;

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }

   @Test
   public void some_panel_test() {
     panel.getDate();
   }
```

I guess when initMocks gets called the magic happens and the panel is constructed. This is when I want to verify some interactions. I understand ideally there would be no code called by the constructor but this is GWT and it is how you init gui components.

I could do it using Mockito WhiteBox but the code is less readable and it requires more code.

Any suggestions welcome. Thanks

Comment: You can do the standard `verify(table).xxx(...)` in a test case, no?

Comment: *"verify calls in method called by constructor"* - a constructor should not do any work beside (very) simple consistency checks. Especially it should not call any methods on the dependencies passed. It should only assign the given parameters to member variables.

Comment: Yes I agree but as mentioned @TimothyTruckle this is a GWT extended class which requires some widget initialisation via the components constructor. So I want to verify that things are initialised correctly or more importantly inform that if the code is changed it has an impact, e.g) a failing test.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @OliverCharlesworth - It was so obvious I didn't realise it ;-) But of course it makes sense.